# How do you export PLC register values from Visilogic?

Tags: plc

I am using Visilogic 9.4.0 to observe the register values of the PLC unit that resides in our robot. I would like to capture snapshots of the register values (particular the MB, MI, and ML registers) before and after a particular set of events.

Is there a way to export all the register values? CSV or Excel outputs would be ideal, but I am open to any reasonable result set. I can do a before and after comparison in the Visilogic IDE by manually inspecting the registers, but in this particular case I am chasing a bug that could be a result of just one of thousands of registers being different. It would be much easier to diff two CSV files than manually comparing thousands of individual registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to achieve what you require would be to write the registers and bits that you require to a datatable, this could be done with a write column command and should not take up too much program.  You could write to successive columns each time you wanted to capture the registers and then export the whole datatable to Excel via the 'Export to Excel' button.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks Tony. In my case the PLC program is provided by another company, and is locked for patent reasons. However, your answer seems to have merit. Ultimately retrieving the data programmatically to perform the diff seems the way to go here. I'm accessing the registers through a driver that was provided, so that is an alternative to modifying the PLC program itself.